# Manually creating a correlation matrix as input for rnorm_multi()

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, data-generation

I am trying to generate a dataframe with the function `rnorm_multi()` from `faux`.
For my `x` argument I want a correlation matrix which includes all correlations from 0 to 1 in steps of .01.

However no matter what I try I am unable to do so as the function returns the error `Error in cormat(r, vars) : correlation matrix not positive definite`.
Is there any way to use this specific matrix as an input correlation matrix for `rnorm_multi()`? Or is it simply not possible?

```
library(faux)
# create an empty 100x100 matrix, fill the lower half with my desired values, transpose it and repeat to make it symmetrical. 

matrix <- matrix(rep(0, 100*100), nrow = 100) 
matrix[lower.tri(matrix)] <- seq(0, .99, .01) 
matrix <- t(matrix) 
matrix[lower.tri(matrix)] <- seq(0, .99, .01) 
diag(matrix) <- 1 # diagonal in correlation matrices should be 1


# generate a dataframe based on the correlation matrix from above

df <- rnorm_multi(100, 100, 0, 1, r = matrix, 
                  varnames = paste("x", seq(0, 1, .01), sep = "."))

# this returns

Error in cormat(r, vars) : correlation matrix not positive definite
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue - had some values too close to 1. I used matrixcalc::is.positive.definite() with different subsets of the matrix to help find where those values were and just manually reduced them a bit.